# Looking to find duplicates in large dataset using indexes in SQL

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I have a database that contains users and emails. This is a very large dataset, so I'm looking for a faster method than a simple SELECT statement. I simply want to find which users have multiple email addresses listed. I believe I have to start like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MyDatabase_Emails
ON MyDatabase (Email ASC)
```

But to be honest I'm new to indexing and my SQL is rusty, so not quite sure what to do after that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count email addresses, then an aggregation is the fastest way.  If you want to start spitting out emails that have duplicates, then in many databases, the following will be faster:

```
select uet.user
from user_email_table uet
where exists (select 1
              from user_email_table uet2
              where uet2.user = uet.user and uet2.email <> uet2.email
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `user_email_table(user, email)`.

This will return duplicates.  A `select distinct` will add to the processing time.

By "multiple" email addresses, I am assuming you want *different* email addresses.  This is the difference between these two queries:

```
select user, count(*)
from user_email_table
group by user
having count(*) > 1;
```

and:

```
select user, count(distinct email)
from user_email_table
group by user
having count(distinct email) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL has two aspects to it. Statements that operate on tables(SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT). There are also statements that define the structure of the data.

An index organizes the data on the disk to increase the speed of select statements. The index is statement that defines the structure of data. From looking at your statement, your index should be phrased:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MyDatabase_Emails
On MyDatabase.user_email_table (Email ASC)
```

An index would be an excellent solution if your SELECT statement is taking too long to finish executing. You would probably want to create an index on the users since you are looking for users with more than one email address.

A SELECT statement to count email addresses is:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(emails)
FROM user_email_table
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(emails) > 1
```